# Zenbook UX501VW not using NVIDIA graphics in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 16.10, asus

I recentyly got an Asus Zenbook UX501VW (FI127T), after a lot of troubles just to get Ubuntu installed, now I got the laptop to a *decent* state.

Now I have Ubuntu 16.10, kernel 4.8.0-39-generic.

I've realized that it doesn't seem to be using the NVIDIA graphics card, and I can't find how to switch to it.

I have both the NVIDIA and Intel Microcode drivers installed and active.

In 'About this Computer' I get:

[image]

Which says it's using the integrated Intel® HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2).

Also, output to

```
$ lspci -vk | grep VGA
```

I only get

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

And also, if I open the NVIDIA X Server Settings, to try to change the graphics card in the Prime setting, I only get this:

[image]

Like it seems as there are options missing.

Any idea how to switch to the NVIDIA card?

Answer (score 2):

Disable Secure Boot in BIOS and you will be able to switch to the Nvidia adapter.

The driver is disabled by Secure Boot.

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to solve it!
Now the problem is that if I set the Intel GPU instead of the NVIDIA one I get the fan at max speed issue. I'll look how to solve it.